# Why new Xcode versions gives a warning about using self inside a block

Tags: xcode, compiler-warnings

Why new Xcode versions gives a warning about using self inside a block.

**Warning:**

> Block implicitly retains 'self'; explicitly mention 'self' to indicate
>   this is intended behavior

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
     NSString *myString;
}
```

And the warning hides when we prefix variable name with `self->`.

I read there is no difference between directly calling variable & self-> in rmaddy's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13919869/4061501)

Comment: Check the last screenshot: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49028910/1801544 It was either not implemented on previous versions of XCode, or was set by default to NO?

Comment: But the older xcode shows warning to access property values. If define variable in `.m` file, older xcode doesn't show warning.

Comment: But what's the LLVM version? Could be a different parsing/checking in the XCode new version.

Comment: Apple LLVM 9.0. Yes. As @knightIdDragon's answer, it gives us clear warning about retaining

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a good warning to have, so I can see them flipping the flag.  More often than not, people are accidently retaining self in blocks, creating retain cycles.  This warning informs you the developer that you may have a possible retain cycle happening.

Basically, if you see the `self` then you know the block is retaining it, where if you do not see the `self`, you may be inclined at first glance to think you are using a local variable.